# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions.setMaxAliasesForCollections(int)'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, snakeyaml

Im my project we are using spring boot 2.6.6 version. When I run the below test class separately I am getting below error.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions.setMaxAliasesForCollections(int)'

If the class runs as part of mvn install its executing without any issues.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT, classes = TestApplication.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WireMockConfig.class})
class ToastNotificationControllerIT {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws IOException {
        
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        
    }

}
```

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.createYaml(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:69)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
'void org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions.setMaxAliasesForCollections(int)'
```

The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader, was loaded from the following location:

```
jar:file:/C:/dev/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.6.6/spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/org/springframework/boot/env/OriginTrackedYamlLoader.class
```

The called method's class, org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/dev/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.23/snakeyaml-1.23-android.jar!/org/yaml/snakeyaml/LoaderOptions.class
jar:file:/C:/dev/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.29/snakeyaml-1.29.jar!/org/yaml/snakeyaml/LoaderOptions.class
```

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions: file:/C:/dev/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.23/snakeyaml-1.23-android.jar
```

I tried exculde the org.yaml dependency from spring boot starter dependency. But the issue is still not resolved.

My Dependency Tree:

```
[INFO] com.selva.test:test-api:jar:1.0.6
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.29:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.60:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.60:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.60:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.68:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.68:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-openfeign-core:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.github.openfeign.form:feign-form-spring:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.github.openfeign.form:feign-form:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.github.openfeign:feign-core:jar:11.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.github.openfeign:feign-slf4j:jar:11.8:compile
[INFO] +- io.github.openfeign:feign-httpclient:jar:11.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.15:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.22:compile (optional)
[INFO] +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.4.2.Final:compile
INFO]  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-spring-web-starter:jar:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-spring-web:jar:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-web-servlet-filter:jar:0.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-tracerresolver:jar:0.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-spring-tracer-configuration-starter:jar:0.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.opentracing:opentracing-noop:jar:0.33.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:jar:1.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core:jar:1.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-common:jar:1.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models:jar:2.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-integration:jar:2.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core:jar:2.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.github.classgraph:classgraph:jar:4.8.69:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.webjars:swagger-ui:jar:3.52.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:jar:0.48:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.6.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.6.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.6:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.21.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.11.22:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.11.22:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.18:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.javafaker:javafaker:jar:1.0.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:android:1.23:test
[INFO] |  \- com.github.mifmif:generex:jar:1.0.2:test
[INFO] |     \- dk.brics.automaton:automaton:jar:1.11-8:test
[INFO] +- com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:jar:2.27.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util-ajax:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-proxy:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-legacy:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-placeholders:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.jknack:handlebars:jar:4.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.jknack:handlebars-helpers:jar:4.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.flipkart.zjsonpatch:zjsonpatch:jar:0.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- au.com.dius.pact.consumer:junit5:jar:4.2.12:test
[INFO] |  +- au.com.dius.pact:consumer:jar:4.2.12:test
[INFO] |  |  +- au.com.dius.pact.core:model:jar:4.2.12:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- au.com.dius.pact.core:support:jar:4.2.12:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr4:jar:4.9.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.antlr:ST4:jar:4.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.abego.treelayout:org.abego.treelayout.core:jar:1.0.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.0.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:61.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging-jvm:jar:2.0.10:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.michael-bull.kotlin-result:kotlin-result-jvm:jar:1.1.12:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- au.com.dius.pact.core:pactbroker:jar:4.2.12:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.5.0-b01:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-core:jar:1.27:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.ktor:ktor-http-jvm:jar:1.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:atomicfu:jar:0.14.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:jar:1.3.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- io.ktor:ktor-utils-jvm:jar:1.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |        \- io.ktor:ktor-io-jvm:jar:1.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- au.com.dius.pact.core:matchers:jar:4.2.12:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.atteo:evo-inflector:jar:1.2.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.github.ajalt:mordant:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.github.ajalt:colormath:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.googlecode.java-diff-utils:diffutils:jar:1.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.json:json:jar:20160212:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.75.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.75.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.75.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.75.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.75.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.75.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.13:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:jar:4.5.13:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:jar:1.4.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:jar:1.6.10:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:jar:1.6.10:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.ktor:ktor-server-host-common:jar:1.4.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.ktor:ktor-server-core:jar:1.4.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.ktor:ktor-http-cio-jvm:jar:1.4.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.75.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.75.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.alpn:alpn-api:jar:1.1.3.v20160715:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:4.1.75.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.75.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-kqueue:jar:4.1.75.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:4.1.75.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.75.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- io.ktor:ktor-network-tls-certificates:jar:1.4.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- io.ktor:ktor-network-tls-jvm:jar:1.4.1:test
[INFO] |  |        \- io.ktor:ktor-network-jvm:jar:1.4.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.6.10:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:13.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.6.10:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:jar:1.6.10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |     +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |     \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
```

Can Anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: You are probably trying to outsmart the dependency management done by the starters or are messing around with manual dependencies yourself. However without knowing what your dependencies are (and the fact that you are messing around with excludes) we cannot answer this.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, I added the dependency tree for your reference. I tried excluding that from spring boot starter but its not working. so I reverted that. I am trying with the dependecy tree that I posted in this question

Comment: `When I run the below test class separately` how is this run?

Comment: I have the spring boot starter class for run this. TestApllication.class

Comment: I want your dependencies list not the tree.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Thanks. I resolved the issue by adding snakeyaml latest dependency in pom and removed the old one in m2 folder and exclude snakeyaml from javafaker dependency and got working

Comment: @Madhesh if you answer your own question I'll upvote the answer. This helped me out.

Comment: @flup, Glad it helped you. Added the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue resolved when adding snakeyaml latest dependency in pom and removed the old one in m2 folder and exclude snakeyaml from javafaker dependency.

Answer (score 5):

Exclude **snakeyaml** from **javafaker**.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
    <version>${javafaker.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And add Updated version of snakeyaml from [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml)

Answer (score 1):

It's in Spring boot application...

```xml
.................

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>

........

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <snakeyaml.version>1.33</snakeyaml.version>
    </properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
.....

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

.....

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.codearte.jfairy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfairy</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

.....
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
......
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                <version>${snakeyaml.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

...................
```

Answer (score 0):

I added snakeyaml library and it worked

```
implementation 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.2'
```